Cannot run wget on linux virtual box vm
I'm trying to install latest wine version according to guide https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu. When I run
sudo wget -O /etc/apt/keyrings/winehq-archive.key https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/winehq.key
I get error
Unable to establish SSL connection.
Ubuntu version - 20.04, wget - 1.20.3. There is access to internet (NAT), I can google in Firefox. I got vm from PostgresPro course.

Welcome to AskUbuntu. There is an insufficient amount of information here to offer a solution. Could you [edit] your question to include the version of Ubuntu you’re running, whether the VirtualBox VM has access to the internet, whether this is a newly-configured VM or one gang has been used for a while, and any other details specific to your installation? This will make it more likely that someone can offer some direction

Is the clock (date and time) of the VM correct?

@FedKad Yes, it is.

Don't install wine this way. Install the tested, working version from the Ubuntu repos. Otherwise you'll be back here in a few days posting a question about how your package system is broken.

@OrganicMarble if they were on 22.04 or newer using the WineHQ repositories is actually safer and more up to date.  The version of Wine in 20.04 that they state they're using is ancient and not supported upstream and has a lot of issues with newer Windows binaries

This is the problem with the site, not with wget.
